# Как обратиться к элементу, который был добавлен после загрузки DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Допустим, у меня есть блочный элемент: `<div class="answers" id="answers"></div>`
После загрузки, по нажатии на кнопку, я хочу вложить в него еще один:

```
$('#add').bind('click', function(){
var question = '<div class="question" id="question">'
$('#answers').append(question);
});
```

После чего я хочу обработать нажатие на новый элемент:

```
$('#question').bind('click', function(){ 
 alert("молодец");
});
```

Проблема в том, что почему - то нажатие не срабатывает. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Для динамических элементов требуется делегирование событий, что-то в духе `$('#answers').on('click', '#question', function() { /*...*/ })`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, получилось :)